# Pass RowData to Custom_func in Jqgrid

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-formatter, mvcjqgrid

I have a jqgrid with certain columns. I am trying to call a custom_function to validate the cell value.

I am also getting a regular expression from the database into rowData, which I want to use to validate the cell value.

```
var ret = jQuery("#settingsListGrid").jqGrid('getRowData', id);
cm.editrules = {
    required: true, 
    custom: true, 
    custom_func: ValidateData, 
    custom_value:ret.RegX 
};
```

So I need to pass rowData to a custom function.

```
ValidateData = function (value, colname, customValue) {
    return customValue.test(value) ?
        [true] :
        [false, "Invalid Data"];
}
```

I want to pass the rowData using **customValue**

Please help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer depend on the fork of jqGrid, which you use. I understand the problem which you wrote, but one have to change the code of jqGrid (the implementation of custom validation) to implement the requirement.

I develop free jqGrid fork of jqGrid after Tony Tomov changed the license agreement of jqGrid, renamed his product in version 4.7.1 to Guriddo jqGrid JS (see [the post](http://www.trirand.com/blog/?p=1438)) and made it commercial (see the prices [here](http://guriddo.net/?page_id=103334)). After starting the development based on the last free 4.7 version I made a lot of changes and improvements in the code and have implemented many new features. The feature which you need is implemented starting with version 4.12.1 (see [here](https://github.com/free-jqgrid/jqGrid/blob/master/README4.12.1.md#the-below-is-the-full-list-of-changes-in-the-version-4121-compared-with-4120)). Thus you can easy solve your problem after updating to the current free jqGrid 4.13.2.

The new feature works as following:

```js
editrules: {
    required: true, 
    custom: ValidateData, 
    custom_value: ret.RegX 
}
```

It's important that one should specify the custom validation function as the value of `custom` property instead of usage `custom_func`. It allows free jqGrid to hold compatibility to old versions (via `custom: true` and `custom_func`), but providing *new parameters* of the validation callback via function as the value of `custom` property.

The new style `ValidateData` will look like

```js
var ValidateData = function (options) {
    return customValue.test(options.newValue) ?
        [true] :
        [false, "Invalid Data"];
}
```

with **only one** `options` parameter, which have many properties which you could use. Such style allows to provide many helpful information without the requirement to have a lot of unneeded parameters. Moreover the style of callback options allows to extend the `options` object in the future versions without breaking compatibility to previous versions.

The `options` parameter have the following properties

- `newValue` - the current (modified) value which need be validated
- `oldValue` - the previous value (the old value) of the cell *before* the modification
- `cmName` - the column name. It could be practical if you use one callback function in many columns and you want to implement a little different behavior for different columns. It could be additionally helpful for producing readable error message in case of validation error.
- `iCol` - the index in the current `colModel` which corresponds the column (the column `cmName`)
- `cm` - the element of `colModel`, which represent the currently validating column.
- `rowid` - the rowid of the current editing row. One can use `getLocalRow` for example to get the content of other columns *before* editing. It's important to remark that `getLocalRow` works only in case of usage `datatype: "local"` or `loadonce: true`. The method `getRowData` or `getCell` can be safe used to get data in form editing mode or to access the data, which are not currently editing (in cell or inline editing mode).
- `iRow` - numeric index of the current editing row from the top of the grid (from the top of HTML `<table>`)
- `oldRowData` - will be set only in case of usage inline editing or cell editing. It's not defined in form editing mode. It represent the values
- `mode` - shows which editing mode is used now. It can be `"addForm"`, `"editForm"` (in case of usage form editing), `"cell"` (cell editing), `"add"` or `"edit"` (inline editing). In some other callback function the property could have two other values: `"filter"` (field from the filter toolbar) or `"search"` (for validation of the field of the searching dialog)
- `tr` and `td` - the DOM elements of the row and cell of the grid which will be edited using *form editing mode*. The properties will be set only in case of form editing.

I hope that the large set of properties of `options` parameter allows you easy implement your requirements on any custom validation.